# Header & Footer not showing up

Tags: php, templates, php-include

So with a little help I was able to get my first mvc framework up and running locally. Now that I've put it up on the server I'm not having any luck.  I believe it's a configuration issue but I can't seem to figure it out.

[Here's a Gif of what it should look like on the server but this is running it locally.](http://imageshack.us/a/img691/9186/f4b.gif)

**Why is nothing showing up when I go directly to the remote path?** ie:

- This does not work:

  - http://tomcat.cit.iupui.edu/alecory/Spring-2014/CIT-31300/Assignment%202/
  - Unless I set the 'URI' constant directly to '/register' which is it's output when running on localhost as seen in the notes below
- This works but isn't what I want & doesn't include the header + footer:

  - http://tomcat.cit.iupui.edu/alecory/Spring-2014/CIT-31300/Assignment%202/views/register.php

---

**config.php**

```
<?php

    include_once 'load.php';

    // Local
    // define ('URL_ROOT', 'http://localhost/');

    // Remote
    define ('URL_ROOT', 'http://tomcat.cit.ipui.edu/alecory/Spring-2014/Assignment%202/');

    // define ('URI', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    // Outputs for:
    //    Local  = /register                                        
    //    Remote = /alecory/Spring-2014/CIT-31300/Assignment%202/views/register.php
    define('URI', '/register'); // <= this is where I could set it myself and 
                                    # it would reroute the URL from
                                    # /Assignment%202/views/register.php   To         
                                    # /Assignment%202/ 
                                    # (only showing /Assignment%202/ in the URL)

    define ('DOC_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    //    Local  = /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CIT-31300/Assignment 2
    //    Remote = /var/www/                       

?>
```

---

**controller.php**

```
<?php 

/**
* Controller
* 
* Description: Basically tells the system what to do and in what order
*/
class Controller
{
    public $load;
    public $model;

    function __construct()
    {
        // Make
        $this->load  = new Load();
        $this->model = new Model();

        // Set the $page = current view/page
        $page = ltrim(URI, '/');

        // Set default page to index
        if (empty($page))
        {
            $page = 'index';
        }

        // Load the Pages
        if (method_exists($this, $page))
        {
            // die(get_include_path());
            require_once DOC_ROOT . '/views/inc/header.php';
            $this->$page();
            require_once DOC_ROOT . '/views/inc/footer.php';
        } 
        else
        {
            require_once DOC_ROOT . '/views/inc/header.php';
            $this->notFound();
            require_once DOC_ROOT . '/views/inc/footer.php';
        }

    }

    // Functions to load the various views
    function index()
    {
        // $data = $this->model->my_user_info();
        $this->load->view('myview.php', $data); 
    }

    // function header()
    // {
    //  $this->load->view('header.php', $data);
    // }

    // function footer()
    // {
    //  $this->load->view('footer.php' $data);
    // }

    function login()
    {
        $this->load->view('login.php', $data); 
    }

    function register()
    {
        $this->load->view('register.php', $data);
    }

    function notFound()
    {
        die('not found');
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: TO get an answer, you need to `define("does not work", "..");` first pelase ;)

Comment: Does not work:
Header and Footer do not load period.
Body will load when the file path is accessed directly.
ie: Assignment 2/views/register.php

Comment: No error messages? Have you turned error reporting on for debugging purposes?

Comment: Yes.  In my php.ini file.

Comment: Impossible. `require_once` triggers an error if the file isn't found. The only possibility if you don't get any error is, that the `__construct()` method isn't called at all.

Comment: Here is a picture of my php.ini file. http://goo.gl/L3xWu9

Comment: Not that it helps much but just to assure everyone it's done. Hmm...

Comment: There is a syntax error in that config file, last line in the picutre. At least it looks like one to mee ^^

Comment: Where did you read that its MVC implementation?

Comment: I'm taking a PHP course and we're covering MVC right now. That's how I know it's MVC.